# Expressions to Find data using QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis-modeler

Im new to the expressions within the model builder.
I have built a model already using two points as a Station And Backsight, with a line between them.
Also my model computes a length of the line and its azimuth, (both are in their own fields).

I would like to use these fields after the layer has been created to define some parameters in the Wedge Buffer tool.
The tool asks For an azimuth and length but I would like to use the previously calculated layer azimuth and length

Is there an expression to "fetch" that data from within the table?